# Next 30 days from a current date

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a procedure that is seelcting the employers and a few datails about them.
I need now to select the ones that were hired in next 30 days from a day given as parameter.

My parameter is defined here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure_emp(p_day IN emp.hiredate%TYPE)  IS
```

When I execute the procedure I'm doing it with procedure_emp('17-DEC-80');

In my procedure declaration right now I have:

```
WHERE p_day = emp.hiredate;
```

Here is where I need to write calculate the next 30 days. I'm not very familiar with working with dates, so please give me a pice of advice.

Comment: I take the "hired in next 30 days" to mean "hired within the next 30 days"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to select employees whose hiredate is between p_day and the following 30 days, you want:

```
where emp.hiredate between p_day and p_day + 30
```

In Oracle, if you have a date-variable (or date constant, for that matter) you can add days simply with the `+ <number>` operator.